# How to fixed a div while we can't see another div?

Tags: jquery, iphone, css, menu, position

I have a question.

I wanna reproduce the effect like Contact in iPhone in jQuery & HTML. 
The div `A` is displaying while there are name which begins by A. 
Then the div `A` disappear and the div `B` appear at exactly the same place.

Did you understand ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i want monkey.  we cant have everything ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but if I did, I suggest using the same `<div>` and just changing the `innerHTML` from A to B to Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand completely. Are you looking for something like this plugin:
http://trevordavis.net/blog/jquery-one-page-navigation-plugin/

Demo here: http://trevordavis.net/play/jquery-one-page-nav/

**UPDATE** - you want something more like this (or a combination of the two): http://blog.yjl.im/2010/01/stick-div-at-top-after-scrolling.html

Comment: Ah ! Yes ! Something like this ! (But I need to change `section 1 menu` to `section 2 menu` when I don't see the section 1 anymore). In the demo, we always see the section 1

Comment: **UDPATE** : Yep. Exactly what I want. But there are no explain ?